# DNSSEC in Spain

Tags: dnssec, tld

I tried to set up DNSSEC for a .es domain. The nameservers are on Cloudflare and GoDaddy is the registrar. I wasn't able and then a 'GoDaddy Guide' (chat support) told me that DNSSEC would generally not be available for .es domains, see https://www.godaddy.com/help/about-es-domains-5533. But the map from the ISOC shows Spain as fully operational (https://www.internetsociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2021-06-14-2021-06-14.png). Now is DNSSEC in Spain available or not? And if, can someone recommend a registrar who provides that functionallity to their customers?

Comment: DNSSEC has been working on es. since 2014. It's probably GoDaddy's fault. They're pretty horrible as a registrar.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you provide an example, please. Using 'dig <domain name> +dnssec' I havn't actually found a single .es website that has DNSSEC implemented. I checked several big providers, registrars and known websites.